# Refactor javascript to allow functions to be called without requiring parenthesis and without using 'get'

Tags: javascript, function

I currently have the following javascript code (loosely modeled after how a similar objective is achieved in `should.js`):

```
var example = function() {
    var isFoo, isBar;

    return {

        baz: function(x) {
            if (isFoo) return x + 2;
            else if (isBar) return x - 2;
        },

        get foo () {
            isFoo = true;
            return this;
        },

        get bar () {
            isBar = true;
            return this;
        },
    }
};
```

This allows me to do something like:

```
example().foo.baz(2);
// 4
```

My primary objective is to allow `foo` and `bar` to be called without requiring parenthesis since they will never take any arguments themselves and makes chaining together calls a lot more readable.  When I passed this code through `uglify.js` it choked on the `get` keyword and when I investigated I found that using the `get` keyword isn't really a great idea (both for performance and compatibility).

Any thoughts on how I could refactor this piece of code so that I can continue to call `foo` and `bar` without parenthesis and without resorting to using the `get` keyword? I've tried defining foo and bar as properties but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You're basically asking how to make the language work in a way that it doesn't want to work.

Comment: IMO, you should just use parenthesis. This makes it clear that foo and bar are special and also goes more in line with things that need parameters (`example().foo('param').baz()`). Anyway, if you want to go wild with a custom DSL I'm not sure limiting yourself to a fluent interface is the most general solution.

Comment: I was just hoping to save some keystrokes, but obviously not worth it.  Parenthesis it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `__defineGetter__`, but that's not a terribly great idea either. Firefox has some new metaprogramming apis, but this is unusable in any other browser.

The baseline is that if you want your code to run in old browsers, this can't be done.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks for confirming!